# How to substitute AutoHotkey Key-sending-scripts on a Mac?

Tags: macos, scripting, autohotkey, diacritics

I'm coming from Windows where I got used to write AHK scripts for everything I needed. Very important for my daily work are hotkeys to send special characters. Like here with Windows+a:

```
#a::ä
```

I don't like the MacOs "normal" way to create this special characters. So I want to write a script for this.
I think that using "Automator" does not work, as it is not running in the background and watching all my keystrokes. Right?
Is there any alternative?

I need it to start automatically on startup and it should be active in all apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) is great for re-mapping key presses. It can remap simply keys by GUI and allows you to configure complex remaps with different key combinations within its [karabiner.json](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/docs/json/root-data-structure/#complex_modifications-in-karabinerjson--profiles).

If you need something more sophisticated that goes beyond simple key events, [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) can help you out. BetterTouchTool doesn't require to write scripts, all is done by GUI.

Comment: Thanks! There's also already the Karabiner script that I needed: https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#german_umlaut

Answer (score 0):

I found Espanso as a great alternative for AHK autocorrect/autoreplace tasks which works both on Windows and Mac.

https://espanso.org/install/

E.g. I can set nbsp automatically just after by/on/after/at automatically to facilitate simpler reading experince in docs and presentations.

When it founds normal space after "by", it replaces it with non-breakable version:

```
matches:
  - trigger: "by "
    replace: "by "
    propagate_case: true
```